# Взаимодействие с десктопными приложениями

Tags: python

Всех приветствую! Подскажите пожалуйста возможно ли как то взаимодействовать с десктопными приложениями с помощью python'а? Например python отправляет запрос приложению(exe), заставляет обработать этот запрос и получает результат этого запроса. 
P.s. Хотелось бы без использования GUI.

Comment: pyautogui.......